# Why two model shows in Tensorboard Graphs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I can't find the reason why two model shows in Tensorboard Graphs page.

I expected the result was two models save separately.
Because the model structure is same but the data is different.
(It means two models are not the same one)

Each model has different object (in my code : FDCModel)

First model **"model1"** has one graph in the Tensorboard.
But second model **"model2"** has **two graphs in the Tensorboard.**

Here is parts of my codes.

```
print('========== model1 train ==========')
n_class = len(data_obj.train_ys[0])
model1 = models.FDCModel(lstm_type, train_fl, input_shape, drop_out, r_drop_out, d_units, r_units, n_layers,
                         dense_fl, optimizer, learning_rate, n_class)
model1.train_model(data_obj.train_x, data_obj.train_ys[0, :], epochs, batches, tb_dir, 'label1')
model1.save_model(model_dir)
model1.use_model(data_obj.train_x[0], data_obj.train_ys[0, 0])

print('========== model2 train ==========')
n_class = len(data_obj.train_ys[1])
model2 = models.FDCModel(lstm_type, train_fl, input_shape, drop_out, r_drop_out, d_units, r_units, n_layers,
                         dense_fl, optimizer, learning_rate, n_class)
model2.train_model(data_obj.train_x, data_obj.train_ys[1, :], epochs, batches, tb_dir, 'label2')
model2.save_model(model_dir)
model2.use_model(data_obj.train_x[0], data_obj.train_ys[1, 0])
```

This is **model1** graph

[image]

This is **model2** graph

[image]

I would appreciate if someone comments about it.

========================

This is my method for train and save tensorboard logs

```
def train_model(self, train_x, train_y, epochs, batches, tb_dir, label_nm):
        modules.check_path(tb_dir)
        log_dir = tb_dir + self.model_name + '_' + label_nm + '_' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
        tb_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, profile_batch=1)

        start_time = timeit.default_timer()
        self.model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batches,
                       callbacks=[tb_callback], verbose=0)
        duration, _ = modules.time_taken(start_time)

        loss, acc = self.model.evaluate(train_x, train_y)
        print('- Train Loss : {}'.format(loss))
        print('- Train Accuracy : {}'.format(acc))
        print('==> Train time [', duration, ' (sec)]')
```

Comment: Please share the code you're using to write the graphs to TensorBoard.

Comment: I'm sorry I just edited. Thanks.

Comment: From the graphs it looks like you have two inputs being put through the model. Perhaps it would help to see the code for `models.FCDModel`? But the code you post does run the model twice (model1 and model2). Are you sure that's not the 2 graphs you are seeing in the second picture?

Comment: @xdhmoore Yes I run the model twice but I thought they are different instances. If I need to reset model or have to do something please let me know.

Comment: I'm not an expert, buy maybe they both get exported to the same TF board result since in your TF board callback you use the same log dir for both. What behavior are you wanting to happen?

Comment: Thank you for your comments @xdmooore. The **train_model()** parameter gets different values so I thought the path wouldn't be same. Also each model has a separated instance therefore I thought **train_model()** can't share the parameters. And it saves at each paths well. I expect each model2 graph shows one structure not two.